# ios UIViewController not calling viewDidUnload

Tags: ios, cocoa, memory-management, iboutlet, viewdidunload

When I simulate a memory warning, `viewDidUnload` should run on *unused* objects, right?

How do I go about figuring out WHY my UIView won't go away?

FYI I'm using **ARC** and every `ivar` is an `IBOutlet` and looks like:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *someView;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "go away"? Are you expecting your view to have a `nil` value after `viewDidUnload`?

Comment: I want it to go out of memory, so in a roundabout way I suppose I do expect a nil value (or something similar). I'm ultimately just trying to make sure my memory management is in check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What class are we looking at here? Only UIViewControllers release their view in case of a mem warning.

If this is a custom class or a custom added view, you should unload it yourself.

Comment: And the view is the 'main view' associated with this controller? Or is it a custom view you added yourself?

Comment: it's view I added my self. fyi this view is associated to it's OWN nib.

Comment: Views that you added and retained yourself will not be released in case of a memory warning. You need to do this yourself. That's what the `viewDidUnload` method` can be used for. But, it looks like you don't actually retain the view...

Comment: I'm using ARC so I would assume ARC would take care of the retain/release. Maybe I am mistaken?